# Jest openHandles - redis not maintaning its state across imports

Tags: node.js, import, redis

I'm trying to do something relatively simple. Instantiate one redis connection and share it across my application, including testing purposes. I  then do a global teardown once all tests have run But I end up creating several separate instances and I'm not clear why..

redis.js

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
let redisClient;
if (!redisClient) {
  console.log("redis client created!");
  redisClient = new Redis({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  });
  redisClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Redis connected.");
  });
  redisClient.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Redis disconnected.");
  });
  redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Redis errror ", err);
  });
}

module.exports = redisClient
```

app.js

```
const redis = require("./redis") //prints redis client created! so the redisClient variable should be set.
```

teardown.js

```
const redis = require("./redis") //prints redis client created! again. It seems the redisClient variable is null...

(async () => {
  await redis.quit()
})()
```

I get the following :

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

       5 |   if (!redisClient) {
       6 |     console.log("Creating a new Redis client.");
    >  7 |     redisClient = new Redis({
         |                   ^
       8 |       host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
       9 |       port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
      10 |     });
```

So my code created another redis instance instead of closing the original. When I try to redisClient in other files (outside Jest), I don't see this issue. I suspect it's something related to Jest's background actions.